# Flutter Firestore - get only 10 docs with their id

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

here I'm trying to get the top 10 names only from my firebase firestore,
and I searched on how I do it with the listview that I have, but I get to nowhere.
so I thought about getting the id of my documents instead.
In my firestore I gave the top 10 documents IDs from 1 to 10, now I'm stuck and I have no idea how to do it. please help.

```
static int id = 1;
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: fireStore.collection(path).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        List<InfoBox> ancients = [];
        try {
          final collection = snapshot.data!.docs;
          for (var collect in collection) {
            final name = collect['Name'];
            final image = collect['Image'];
            final collectionWidget = InfoBox(
                ancientName: name,
                ancientImage: image
            );
            ancients.add(collectionWidget);
          }
        }catch(e){
          print('problems in stream builder \n error : $e');
        }
        return Expanded(
            child:ListView(
              children: ancients,
            )
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably searching for `limit()` function. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying):

> To limit the number of documents returned from a query, use the limit method on a collection reference

You can implement it like this:

```dart
fireStore.collection(path).limit(10).snapshots();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ListView to this List if else everything is ok and u are getting data in list then this will work.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: ancients.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

    return ListTile(
    leading: new Image.network(ancients[index].ancientImage),
  title: new Text(ancients[index].ancientName),
    )
  },
  )
```